# jquery:-[object Object] error

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a validation.js file

```
var name = $("#name");

    $.ajax({
        type:       "get",
        url:        "test.jsp",
        data:           "name="+name,
        success:    function(msg) {

            $('#result').hide();

            $("#result").html(msg)
            .fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
```

test.jsp

```
</head>
    <body>
        <h1><%
        String user=request.getParameter("name");
        out.print(user);
        %></h1>
    </body>
```

the login user.jsp file

```
<form method="post" id="customForm" action="welcome.html">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
                            <span id="nameimage"></span>

            <span id="nameInfo"></span>
                          <p id="result"></p>  
        </div>
```

i have to show the username in my form as soon as user goes to next feild in my form.but
it is showing [object Object] error in place where p tag starts

Comment: What happens what you do `console.log(msg)`? What does that object look like?

Comment: [object Object] is not an error, its the string representation of a basic javascript object. Which means your server is probably printing a JSON or an object of some kind.

Answer (score 12):

looks like `msg` isn't what you expect. I think you want `msg.responseText`

The reason you see [object Object] is because `msg` is of type object and you pass it into `.html` which will convert it to a string. And thus the html is filled with the string representation of object which in this case is "[object Object]"

Answer (score 5):

You will need to pass the value or the text of the #name object. Like this:

```
var name = $("#name").val();
var name = $("#name").text();
```

Comment: thks...the error is removed but the output is coming is next line below text box,i want it to appear in  the same line besides the name textbox

Comment: I also want to compare the msg value in function(msg) value with a string

Answer (score 0):

`msg` appears to be a document object, rather than a string containing the appropriate name.  It seems to me that you want `$('#response').text($(msg).find('h1').text());`

Answer (score 0):

The good-old IE expects to redirect somewhere when you use an anchor tag. If you have something like the following:

```
<a href="javascript: submit()">Submit</a>
```

IE will show you blank page with `[Object object]` when using JSON, even if `submit()` uses ajax.

You can use onClick instead or `javascript:void sumbit()` like this:

```
<a id="btn-submit">Submit</a>
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#btn-submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        submit();
    });
</script>
```

I didn't test the void solution but a coworker of mine says that's the one he uses.