# use the message returned by $.ajax function

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "test.jsp",
    data: "user=" + name.val(),
    success: function(msg) {

        $('#result').hide();

        $("#result").html(msg).fadeIn("slow");

        if (msg == "available") {
            //want to disaply image
```

alert('message: ' + msg);
            }
        }
    });

i want to display available and a image with a tick mark to indicate correctness,but the above code is not working
alert is not working

Comment: Not only is your code not formatted, when I tried to fix it, the brackets didn't match up so I'm not sure if you overlooked it when pasting, or it's actually an error in your code. Please take some time to make your question readable. The `?` at the top-right of the edit box might help.

Comment: Where is the image? Already on the page? In the appended response? It is already hidden?

Comment: alert(msg) to check returning value of your function.

Comment: @karim79 if you want more information then go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924383/jquery-object-object-error  here she already asked this question

Answer (score 0):

```
//want to disaply image
$('#myImage').show();
```

If the image doesn't show up, you might want to add an alert

```
alert('message: ' + msg);
```

Comment: where is 'name' defined?  name.val() will be throwing an error if it isn't defined somewhere.